# Copying/moving an object in gcc breaks its member lambdas

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda, polymorphism, visitor-pattern

Let's say, there is a simple polymorphic relationship:

```
class base {
public:
    void update() const { updater(); }
    void accept(visitor const &visitor) {
        visitor_acceptor(visitor);
    }
protected:
    base(std::function<void()> const &updater, 
         std::function<void(visitor const &)> const &visitor_acceptor) 
        : updater(updater), visitor_acceptor(visitor_acceptor) {}
protected:
    std::function<void()> updater;
    std::function<void(visitor const &)> visitor_acceptor;
};

class derived_int : public base {
public:
    derived_int() : base(
            [this]() { ++value; }, 
            [this](visitor const &visitor) { visitor(value); }
        ), value(0) {}
protected:
    int value;
};

class derived_string : public base {
public:
    derived_string() : base(
            [this]() { value += '1'; }, 
            [this](visitor const &visitor) { visitor(value); }
        ), value("") {}
protected:
    std::string value;
};
```

And a storage class to hold them all together:

```
class storage {
public:
    void add(base const &input) { pointers.emplace_back(std::make_unique<base>(input)); }
    void add(base &&input) { pointers.emplace_back(std::make_unique<base>(std::move(input))); }

    void update() {
        for (auto &ptr : pointers)
            ptr->update();
    }
    void print() {
        visitor printer;
        for (auto &ptr : pointers)
            ptr->accept(printer);
    }
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<base>> pointers;
};
```

main:

```
int main() {
    storage s;

    derived_int temp1;
    derived_string temp2;
    s.add(temp1);
    s.add(temp2);
    s.add(derived_int{});
    s.add(derived_string{});

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        s.update();

    s.print();
}
```

On both `clang (10.0)` and `MSVC (19.25)` this [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) works correctly, while `gcc (9.3.0)` outputs:

```
derived_int: 5
derived_string: 11111
derived_int: -71963
derived_string: 1
```

It seems that there's some kind of object life issue, as explicitly created variables don't cause any problems, but I cannot quite pinpoint it down.

Comment: As soon as you capture `this` the function object member isn't suitable for copy or move. The captured `this` is a copy and still points to the original instance that generated the lambda.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux So should I overload copy/move constructor or something and somehow replace the lambda? Or is there a better solution for the problem?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux And also, if its a problematic behavior, why do both `msvc` and `clang` work correctly?

Comment: Presumably the `this` you copied is no longer a valid pointer and using it is Undefined Behavior. It might work sometimes, might crash others and might do anything imaginable. Different compilers can generate different assembly. As far as the language is concerned there is no logic or reason for how and why one implementation's expression of UB is different from another.

Comment: If you tried to handle move and copy yourself, you would still need to create entirely new lambdas with different capture values. You won't be able to extract the original lambda's function body to do this. You could try adding a `this` equivalent argument to your function objects instead of capturing `this` but I'm not sure if this will be compatible with your design.

Comment: One possible quick-fix would be to make your types not copyable and not movable and *always* manage them using `std::unique_ptr`. If you never copy or move your type then your lambda's captured pointer is never invalidated.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Then should I try doing something similar to writing an `explicit lambda` (an object with an overloaded `operator()()`) and handling the pointers myself?

Comment: Better IMO is to delete move/copy, and change `storage` to take directly smart pointers.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux @Jarod42 But then I'd be forced to write `std::make_unique<...>()` explicitly when passing object to the storage, wouldn't I?

Comment: @JohnCvelth Yes, you lose value semantics. It's possible to write your own wrapper for this that has value semantics. It would have a `std::unique_ptr` member. Move semantics would work out-of-the-box. You could write your own copy assignment and copy constructor if your type has some sort of `clone` feature.

Comment: You might still add `emplace` to have `s.emplace<derived_int>(/*..*/);`

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux If so, I'm already thinking of more or less Factory-like approach for that, or is this a bad idea?

Comment: @Jarod42 Nice suggestion, but in real project I'm already using variadic templates to accept a few object at once. `emplace` doesn't relly go well with that.

Comment: @JohnCvelth: `std::piecewise_construct` and/or tuple with tag might resolve that, but that extra layer might be too verbose...

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm thinking of something like a bunch of overloaded `std::unique_ptr<...> make_derived_*()` functions.